# ImagePullbackOff : minikube k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hadoop, minikube

i'm trying to add spark to minikube with using this blog as tutorial to help me : https://medium.com/@rewelle/d%C3%A9ploiement-dune-architecture-compl%C3%A8te-big-data-avec-kubernetes-570eaa0e627

i get ImagePullBackOff like status when he tried to add the pod : spark-standalone-worker-1.

[image]

And that's what i get when i run : `kubectl describe pods sparl-standalone-worker-1` :

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a temporary failure. Try recreating the Pod.

Comment: @zer0 no it's not working

Comment: Did you try to delete and recreate the pod? All the pods are running on the same node, so this is not a network connectivity problem. Redeploying should work.

Comment: Unauthorized,  authentication required ?

Comment: @zer0 they are not in the same node, i have 3 node and each one in node

Comment: what happens if you try to pull the docker image manually?

Comment: You're using minikube, which is a single node setup. Please verify this. Also, log into your node which has the failing pod, and try to access the internet `ping google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The status **ImagePullBackOff** means that a Pod couldn’t start, because Kubernetes couldn’t pull a container image. The ‘BackOff’ part means that Kubernetes will keep trying to pull the image, with an increasing delay (‘back-off’).

This is a very common reason for **ImagePullBackOff** since [Docker introduced rate limits on Docker Hub.](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits) Once you hit your maximum download limit on Docker Hub, you’ll be blocked and this might cause your ImagePullBackOff error. You’ll either need to sign in with an account, or find another place to get your image from.

This error can also happen if your registry requires SSL/TLS authentication, but you don’t trust its certificate. Make sure you follow the instructions to set up TLS authentication.

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to pull image ... authentication required`

You need to create a Secret [for the Docker Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), or you have been rate-limited from pulling new containers for a while.